# How to bind dataset values into text box in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have aspx webform that contains search box and button like this
[image]

In code behind NT search method called using web method like this

```js
 [WebMethod]
        public static void GetNT(string NTID)
        {
            try
            {
                myService.myServiceClient me = new myService.myServiceClient();
                DataSet dsResult = me.InfobyNt(NTID);
                    ware1 _ware1 = new ware1();
                    _ware1.AssignValues(dsResult);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

i had result on dataset and passed to assignvalues method, there i bind values like this

```js
protected void AssignValues(DataSet dsResult1)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dsResult1 != null && dsResult1.Tables[0].Columns.Count > 1)
                {
                    Response.Write(dsResult1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EMPNAME"].ToString());
                    // foreach(var datas in dsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
                    //{
                    string name = dsResult1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EMPNAME"].ToString();
                    txtFname.Text = name.ToString();
                    txtEmilSgs.Text = Convert.ToString(dsResult1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EMAILID"]);
                    txtPrgSgs.Text = Convert.ToString(dsResult1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PROGNAME"]);
                    txtMname.Text = Convert.ToString(dsResult1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MANAGERNAME"]);
                    //}
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('fail')</script>");
                    btnSgsLoad.Text = "Can't find NT ID";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }

        }
```

while binding data from dataset an error thrown like this
[image]

can somebody help me how to bind dataset values into asp:textbox

Comment: first check if that dataset table contains the column name you are trying to bind?

Comment: yes it has column names with values

Answer (score 0):

`dsResult1.Tables[0].Columns.Count > 1` replace this with `dsResult1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 1` because there is no reason to count columns of dataset table, probably your dataset is not null but tables in your dataset is null check if your dataset has tables and rows as per your expectation otherwise you will get the same error. and

```
string name = dsResult1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EMPNAME"].ToString();
```

this line is getting null value to "name" string that's the reason behind this error.

Check you dataset is full fill with all records

Comment: Thanks, i had change following on my code, still i got same issue, null reference error popped on txtFname.Text

Comment: I had fixed that issue using  InitializeComponent(); method, but while bind data into textbox, value is not showing into text box

Comment: Check you dataset fill logic it might give null value as your dataset not filled properly.
DataSet dsResult = me.InfobyNt(NTID);
At this line put a debug and check dsresult fill with some proper data.
try to add watch using this line "dsResult1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EMPNAME"].ToString()"
if value is null or enpty than in InfobyNt method has some logic issues to fill dataset

Comment: are you using ajax update panel if yes you have to update that updatepanel like this way updatepanelId.update();

Comment: i'm not using any update panel, everything inside a div element

Comment: Okk than you have one way to overcome this issue you have to change a logic to bind a data to the fields like you have a web method "GetNT" in this method convert this dataset to json and onSuccess method of Jquery ajax where you are calling this Webmethod you have to fill out all fields using jquery.

Comment: [For Webmethod](http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Jquery-JSON-Add-Edit-Update-Delete-in-Asp-Net) take a look at this link and find keyword "Edit operation." 
there you will get an idea for webmethod implementation in your case change return type "string" in replace of "void" and for convert dataset to json take a look at this link [Convert to json from dataset or datatable](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/9bff34/3-ways-to-convert-datatable-to-json-string-in-asp-net-c-sharp/).
There is also a onsuccess function to bind json value to textbox